# Better solutions for a annoying nested if statements in routes of php application

Tags: php, rest, if-statement, optimization

I am using slim php, but this isn't much of specific in just slim, this is common among routes of different php frameworks, especially when working with rest apps.

Okay, here is the most common route that can be found in a blog or archiving application

```
 $app->get('docs(/:year(/:month(/:day)))', function($y=0;$m=0;$d=0) use ($app){
    if ($year !== 0 && $month !==0 && $day !== 0) {
        // query database with conditions of year, month, day
    } else if ($year !== 0 && $month !== 0) {
        // query database with conditions of year, month
    } else if ($year !== 0) {
        // query database with conditions of year
    } else {
        // query database, return all
    }
 })
```

Additionally you want to add `get` parameters to narrow down results, like `limit`, `offset`

```
 $app->get('docs(/:year(/:month(/:day)))', function($y=0;$m=0;$d=0) use ($app){
    // additionally you optionally allowed filters like: limit, offset, all     
    $tmpLimit = $app->request()->get('limit');
    $tmpOffSet = $app->request()->get('offset');

    $limit = isset($tmpLimit) ? $tmpLimit : 10;
    $offset = isset($tmpOffSet) ? $tmpOffSet : 0;

    ... below add the code previously, and query would change according to if filters(limit,offset) has been set.
 })
```

Are there any more solutions to this? Have too much code tells me that I am not doing it right.

Comment: Conditionally construct your query: `if ($year) $where[] = 'year = ?'; ... sprintf('WHERE %s', join(' AND ', $where)) ...`?

Comment: one problem I encountered with this @deceze is that, if you pass the `$query` constructed conditionally like you mentioned, I will have a problem in binding variables, like so:
   https://gist.github.com/8566bba7235a6ba12276.git

That is if i only provide the year, or year and the month only.

Comment: `if ($year) { $where[] = 'year = :year'; $bind['where'] = $year; } ... query($query, $bind) ...`?!

Comment: @deceze would you mind if I posted an answer?

Comment: Of course not. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) and [@ramon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601704/ramon-de-la-fuente) for guiding me to the whole process of refactoring my code,

First I was given the idea of **conditionally constructing** the SQL statements, which lead me to this:

```
if ($year !== 0) {
   $where[] = 'YEAR(date_created) = :year';
   $bind['where'] = $year; 
}
... // if month, if year..
...
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE %s', join(' AND ', $where));
Document::raw_query($query, $bind)->find_array();
```

Which will or might cause issues, according to @ramon, he proposed to used a query builder,
so that:

*I can do something like:*

```
$queryBuilder
->select('b.id', 'b.title')
->from('blog', 'b');
```

Looking at the basic where methods provide by paris, as seen in its documentation, I cannot pass a native sql function in the `where` method of the active record library, but digging up more, I realized that it was build on top of idiorm, I just have to look at the documentation if passing function through the where clause is possible, and by playing around my IDE for a bit, I found out that `where_raw` exists.

And I came up with this...

```
$where = array();
$bind = array();

if (!is_null($day)) {
    $where[] = 'DAY(`date_created`) = ?';
    $bind[] = $day;
}

if (!is_null($month)) {
    $where[] = 'MONTH(`date_created`) = ?';
    $bind[] = $month;
}

if (!is_null($year)) {
    $where[] = 'YEAR(`date_created`) = ?';
    $bind[] = $year;

    $query = sprintf('%s', join(' AND ', $where));
    $foo = Foo::where_raw($query, $bind)
            ->order_by_desc('date_created')
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->find_array();
} else {
    $documents = Foo::order_by_desc('date_created')
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->find_array();
}
```

I am a bit confident of accepting inputs from the user, the orm prepared the query before execution, I think that'll do some security checks.

Comment: @Vaidas 's solution is better

Answer (score 2):

You can use middlewares([Route-Middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Middleware)/[Middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Middleware-Overview)) and/or hooks([Hooks-Overview](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview)) to keep your route simple.

## Route-Middleware:

```
$mw = function($app) {
  return function() use($app) {
     $tmpLimit = $app->request()->get('limit');
     $tmpOffSet = $app->request()->get('offset');
     $app->docsLimit = isset($tmpLimit) ? $tmpLimit : 10;
     $app->docsOffSet = isset($tmpOffSet) ? $tmpOffSet : 0; 
  };
};
```

route:

```
$app->get('/docs(/:year(/:month(/:day)))', $mw($app),function($y=0,$m=0,$d=0) use ($app) {

    echo $app->docsLimit."<br/>";
    echo $app->docsOffSet."<br/>";

    ... your previously code
});
```

## Hooks:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.router', function() use($app){
    if (strpos($app->request()->getPath(), '/docs') === 0) {
        $tmpLimit = $app->request()->get('limit');
        $tmpOffSet = $app->request()->get('offset');
        $app->docsLimit = isset($tmpLimit) ? $tmpLimit : 10;
        $app->docsOffSet = isset($tmpOffSet) ? $tmpOffSet : 0;
    }
});
```

route:

```
$app->get('/docs(/:year(/:month(/:day)))', function($y=0,$m=0,$d=0) use ($app) {

    echo $app->docsLimit."<br/>";
    echo $app->docsOffSet."<br/>";

    ... your previously code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should look into query builder objects a little bit. For example the one in [Doctrine DBAL](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). This allows you to contruct queries conditionally, without concatting strings together (which opens pandora's box for all kinds of possible errors and security issues):

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('b.id', 'b.title')
    ->from('blog', 'b');

if ($year) {
    $queryBuilder->where('b.year = :year')
                 ->setParameter('year', $year);
}
if ($month) {
    queryBuilder->where('b.month = :month')
                ->setParameter('month', $month);
}
if ($day) {
    $queryBuilder->where('b.day = :day')
                 ->setParameter('year', $day)
}
```

Besides that, it looks like you're putting all the functionality in the route, but you should look into separating some of the tasks into services. Quickly scanning the slimphp documentation I can't find any concept of "services", but all it means is that you add a separate function to the $app so you can re-use that functionality. It stands to reason you will want to fetch "blogs" from multiple routes. It should be as simple as (docs [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview)) :

```
$app->findBlogPosts = function($y = null, $m = null, $d = null) use ($app) {
  // do the DB stuff here, return results
}
```

I changed the parameters de default to `null`, as a $year value of `0` has no meaning. If you intend to say "this thing possibly has no value", use the language's concept of "null" - every programming language has such a concept.

Comment: I would like to keep it simple, injecting services would add complexity to my code,. But I would accept your suggestion of changing  0 to null.

Comment: Be careful with the 'complexity' argument. Adding services might reduce complexity in the long run, once you start duplicating code into multple routes ;-)

Comment: also the query builder I think would not allow something like
`YEAR(date_created) = :year`, right? I am already using an idiorm, and paris, that could do what you suggests, still I need to use the `raw_query` because I need to pass that function.

Comment: whilst I agree with you with the long run, yeah, you know I am a fan of angularjs, and other frameworks that beautifully implemented SOC, I still need to keep it as simple as this., for now.

Comment: Sounds well though through, that's most important. As for the query builder allowing native SQL functions; you can run a string through the db->connection but that kind of negates the use of a queryBuilder.